# ng-show not returning true in any case

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to show a div if the condition written inside matches. Though in some of the case it do matches but still the ng-show div is not getting shown may be ng-show condition do not return true. I am trying to compare each of the list values with the variable groupAdmin which is set in the scope in the controller.

```
<div class="list__item__right">
     <div ng-show='{{groupParticipants|
    domainFilter}}==="{{groupAdmin|
    domainFilter}}"'>
        <span>Admin</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use like this

Try this

```
<div ng-show=(groupParticipants|
    domainFilter)===(groupAdmin|
    domainFilter)>
```